# Convert PostgreSQL to SqlAlchemy query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a simple query in PostgreSQL which I need to convert to SQLAlchemy.

```
SELECT table1.name,table2.ip,table2.info 
FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 
ON(table1.name=table2.hostname) 
GROUP BY table1.name;
```

I have tried using this with no success:

```
session.query(table1.name
              ,table2.ip
              ,table2.info).distinct().join(table2).group_by(table1.name)
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance
Ishwar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. I was actually missing the ON condition in query:

session.query(table1.name
              ,table2.ip
              ,table2.info
              ).distinct().outerjoin(table2 , table1.name=table2.hostname
              ).group_by(table1.name)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you would do it using the Expression API

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/expression_api.html

1. Define your table, for example:

   ```
   table1 = table('table1',
       column('name', String())
   )

   table2 = table('table2',
       column('ip', String()),
       column('info', String()),
       column('hostname', String()),
   )
   ```
2. Compose your query, like:

   ```
   my_query = select([table1.c.name,
                      table2.c.ip,
                      table2.c.info]
              ).select_from(
                      table1.outerjoin(table2, table1.c.name == table2.c.hostname)
              ).group_by(table1.c.name)
   ```
3. Execute your query, like:

   ```
   db.execute(my_query)
   ```

Comment: Though it doesn't answer the question exactly, I got a direction to move ahead. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your answer what the problem is, but my shoot at this query would be:

```
session.query(table1.name
             ,table2.ip
             ,table2.info)\
       .outerjoin(table2)\
       .group_by(table1.name)
```